# django signal sending email after registering user

Tags: python, django, django-signals

i have a user model where after creating the model I want to send email from signal.

I have a function in my `signals.py`

```
def notify_after_registration(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    user = instance.username
    email_subject = 'Account confirmation'
    email_body = "some message"            
    send_mail(
        email_subject, 
        email_body, 
        settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
        [instance.email, 
        fail_silently=False
    )
```

at the bottom i have

```
post_save.connect(notify_after_registration, sender=User)
```

When I register the user user is saved but email is not sent.. What is wrong ?

Comment: Quite a few things could be wrong here... Did you at least try calling the `notify_after_registration` function manually (from the Django shell) ? If yes, what did you get ? (and if no, you know what you have to do...)

Comment: `signals.py` is not automatically imported by Django, it could be that your receiver never gets connected, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/29698337/202168

Comment: I miss some considerations: Have you verified if function is called? Have you change fail_silently to true to isolate issue? Is a typo snipped code bad indentation send_mail line ?

Comment: Would be simpler and bug free to just override the models save method and send the email from there.

Comment: `[instance.email` is missing a closing bracket too.

Answer (score 0):

the code from your signals.py by default is not imported anywhere, so you need to add it import in some part of your app, for example in file with models (or, one of models if your have many such files)